# Replacing hash on scroll with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have elements, which when clicked produces dynamic hashes when clicked. When I scroll to a different section I want hashes to be removed. I am using the following code to remove the hash. It seems to work however it get `#undefined` as the hash.

```
$(document).scroll(function() {
if ($('.175').hasClass('act-link')) {
window.location.hash = $(this).attr('');
}
else {
//do something else
}
});
```

Comment: `history.replaceState(null, null, ' ');` to remove the hash

Comment: `$(this).attr('');` will only ever give you undefined. I'm not sure what you're expecting to happen with that code in order to give you an alternative.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I dont want anything to appear after the hash

Comment: In that case @BrettGregson has you answer. You can also refer to the second answer in the duplicate I marked